# Problems running Python script in XCode

Tags: python, xcode

I'm trying to run a python script in Xcode before compiling the sources.

I have created a new **Run Script Phase** and dragged it before the **Compile Sources** section.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96MFQ.png)

[image]
The build operation fails saying the following:

```
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 770, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 811, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipfile, "File is not a zip file"
zipfile.BadZipfile: File is not a zip file
```

Note: the script works properly if it's set to run after compiling resources.

Any idea what could I do ? 
Thank you!